# How do I linkify Twitter usernames using PHP preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, twitter, preg-replace

I want to search the text property of my twitter status objects and swap out @username for `<a href="http:/twitter.com/username">@username</a>`. What I have tried so far looks like this:

```
$pattern = '/([@]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)/';
$replace = '<a href="http://twitter.com/\2">\1\2</a>';
$new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

But it doesn't do any replacements. I know my reg exp is wrong but I can't figure out exactly where/why. Help?

**Edit: ... sample data as requested?

```
$text = '@janesmith I like that, but my friend @johndoe said it better.';
```

Desired output:

[@janesmith](http://twitter.com/janesmith) I like that, but my friend [@johndoe](http://twitter.com/johndoe) said it better.

`***** MY FULL FUNCTION *****`

```
function linkify($string, $twitter=false) {

    // reg exp pattern
    $pattern = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

    // convert string URLs to active links
    $new_string = preg_replace($pattern, "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $string);

    if ($twitter) {
        $pattern = '/@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/';
        $replace = '<a href="http://twitter.com/\1">@\1</a>';
        $new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $new_string);
    }

    return $new_string;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input and the desired output?

Comment: can you put in some sample data for testing?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't do any replacements", do you mean it removes the username but doesn't put a link in, or do you mean it leaves the input string unmodified?

Comment: unmodified -- with the full function above, regular URLs are replaced succesfully, but @usernames are left as untouched strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why is the `\` there before `_`? Does it work if you take out the `\`? Though that shouldn't have broken the functionality...

It might be helpful to change the `\1` to `\\1` so that you're sure the backslash is escaped; or better (since PHP 4.0.4) `$1`. But again, it should have worked as-is, within single quotes.

Also, you can simplify:

```
$pattern = '/@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/';
$replace = '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>';
```

Comment: Good points -- I added the extra business around the @ when it wasn't working in case that was the problem. I just simplified as you suggest and removed the `\ ` before the `_` but it still doesn't replace.

Comment: @Jason, what happens if you use `$1` instead of `\1`?

Comment: @Jason, I tried the above at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html and it worked fine. So I'm kind of at a loss as to what else could be wrong.

Comment: Your fix ended up working, so long as I remembered to pass TRUE as the second argument of my linkify() function call. *smacks head*

Answer (score 2):

I have update a little the function to support hashtags too:

> function linkify($string, $twitter=false) {
>
> // reg exp pattern
>
> $pattern = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
>
> // convert string URLs to active links
>      $new_string = preg_replace($pattern, "\0", $string);
>
> if ($twitter) {
>
> ```
>    $pattern = '/\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/';
>
>    $replace = '<a href="http://twitter.com/\1">@\1</a>';
>
>    $new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $new_string);
>
>
>    $pattern = '/\#([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/';
>
>    $replace = '<a href="http://twitter.com/search/#\1">#\1</a>';
>
>    $new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $new_string);
> ```
>
> }
>
> return $new_string;
>   }

Answer (score 0):

Found this to work for URLs, @usernames, and #hashtags:

http://davidwalsh.name/linkify-twitter-feed

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has updated their api and, at least to me, it is way more user friendly. Check out the documentation found at the dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-for-websites [click here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-for-websites). You must first creat an app, follow the step-by-step instructions, then you create a widget. The widget you see below displays my tweets, but you can create one that displays all the action on your timeline or the results of searches, lists, etc...

```
     <a class="twitter-timeline" ref="https://twitter.com/SKAmerica" data-widget-id="359949405157203970">Tweets by @SKAmerica</a>
     <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id))js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```