# Replacing words starting with @ with a twitter link

Tags: php, twitter, preg-replace

I need to replace all words starting with @ in a text with the corresponding link to that twitter account. Right now I'm using something like this:

```
$tweet_text = preg_replace('/(@\w+)/', '<a href=\'#\'>\1</a>', $string);
```

That works, but the link goes nowhere. I've decided to use a combination of strpos() and substr() to get the actual word and then be able to link to that twitter account, but I was wondering if there's a better solution. Any ideas?

Examples:

Before replacement:

```
'Imperfection is the new perfection... RT @xHausOfCandy: @katyperry i think your bottom teeth and your wonk eye make you even more adorable.'
```

After replacement:

```
'Imperfection is the new perfection... RT <a href=''#''>@xHausOfCandy</a>: <a href=''#''>@katyperry</a> i think your bottom teeth and your wonk eye make you even more adorable.'
```

Desired:

```
'Imperfection is the new perfection... RT <a href=''http://twitter.com/xHausOfCandy''>@xHausOfCandy</a>: <a href=''http://twitter.com/katyperry''>@katyperry</a> i think your bottom teeth and your wonk eye make you even more adorable.'
```

Hope it's more clear now!

Comment: Could you post a sample 'before' and 'after' to demonstrate what you're doing?

Comment: What is the actual output of $tweet_text after replacement?

Comment: He doesn't know what to put in place of #...that's the question.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044014/how-do-i-linkify-twitter-usernames-using-php-preg-replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the name in it's own capture group and use \2 when referring to it in the replacement.

```
$tweet_text = preg_replace('/(@(\w+))/', '<a href="http://twitter.com/\2">\1</a>', $string);
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of this? I'm not following entirely.

Comment: Done. Took me a while since I'm from mobile. Have a look  :-) @luqita

Comment: Could just use 1 group with `'/@(\w+)/'` though

Comment: @Esailija But then the link won't include the @ symbol.

Comment: I prefer to keep things a dynamic as possible. If for some reason I would want to change @ to &, I only need to change in one place. Your argument is valid though.

Comment: @Truth that depends on twitter, if you want different symbol in the link's text then actually there is even more reason to use `'@\1'` because it won't depend on what twitter uses for symbol :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [twitter-text](https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-php) library

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'Imperfection is the new perfection... RT @xHausOfCandy: @katyperry i think your bottom teeth and your wonk eye make you even more adorable.';
$tweet_text = preg_replace('/@(\w+)/', '<a href="http://twitter.com/#\1">@\1</a>', $string);
```